# PHP script cannot stop the program which is run from shell script in linux

Tags: php, linux, shell

I wrote a shell script in linux to check if one of my program (say programA) is running, if it stopped, it will restart the program.

ok, I also have a php script which hav start & stop button to start and stop the same program from the server side. If the program is already run by the shell script, clicking on start button will NOT run multiple of the same program.

**THE PROBLEM IS:**  if PHP script works fine by itself. But the PHP script cannot close the program if it is run by the shellscript. Is this a permission issue or something that I havent been aware of? (I already did chmod 777 programA btw...)

UPDATE:
in my PHP script, it calls exec("kill -9 PID_of_programA") to kill the program.
I tried to change it to $r = shell_exec("kill -9 PID_of_programA") and echo $r gives me nothing...

Comment: What error or information do you get when you try to close the program in PHP when the program has been started by the shell script?

Comment: nothing happens. I use PHP to execute linux command "kill -9 PID" to kill it.

Comment: The discussion of permissions refers to the fact that `kill -9` often needs to be run as `sudo kill -9`. So the recommendation is to run your php script with `sudo`. Also, `kill` does not return any message upon success, at least on my system, so echoing your `$r` variable is not definitive. Better to list active processes.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running your program with a user that has no privileges to close other programs... Have you tried to run as super user?

Comment: I dont have any knowledge in this field. I already set 777 for that file, so I think any user can kill this program?

Comment: @HughH File permissions are only about viewing and editing files. Setting permissions to `777` won't help with killing it when it's running.

Comment: @WaleedKhan so what do I need to do to fix this issue?

Comment: You can have the privileges to open, edit and run the file, but you may not have the privileges to execute certain actions. There is no fix, what you have to do is to run the program as super user:

    $ sudo programA

and enter your password. If you don't have sudo installed, you can do:

    $ su

and enter the super user password, and the execute the program.